# Ajax request throws 500 error, but the request works

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I setup an API controller to handle an ajax request. Every time the Ajax request is made from the script below I get a 500 error:

```
POST http://localhost:58463/api/Reservations 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery-2.1.0.min.js:4
l.cors.a.crossDomain.send jquery-2.1.0.min.js:4
o.extend.ajax jquery-2.1.0.min.js:4
(anonymous function) Confirm?spaceNumber=5:129
o.event.dispatch jquery-2.1.0.min.js:3
r.handle
```

but the weird thing is - the request actually succeeds. It creates a reservation. How is that possible, and how can I resolve the error?

View:

```
@model *********.Models.Reservation
@section Scripts {
   $(document).ready(function () {
        console.log('ready');
        $('#confirmationForm').submit(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var $form = $(this);
            $.ajax({
                type: $form.prop('method'),
                url: $form.prop('action'),
                data: $form.serialize(),
                dataType: "json",
                traditional: true,
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log('yes!');
                }, 
                error: function(response) {
                    console.log('no');
                }
            });
        });
    });
}

<div class="section about" style="height: 100%;">
    <div id="main-content" class="main-content">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="section-heading">
                <h2 class="red">Confirm Your Reservation</h2><br />
            </div>
            <div class="section-content">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="hero-buttons text-center">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-gray btn-lg white">No</a>
                        <form action="/api/Reservations" method="post" id="confirmationForm">
                            @Html.Hidden("UserName", @Model.UserName)
                            @Html.Hidden("SpaceNumber", @Model.SpaceNumber)
                            <input type="submit" value="Yes" class="btn btn-red btn-lg white">
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

APIController:

```
public class ReservationsController : ApiController
{
    private MyContext db = new MyContext();

    // POST api/Reservations
    public HttpResponseMessage PostReservation(Reservation reservation)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            reservation.Game = db.Games.FirstOrDefault(g => g.ID == AppSettings.CurrentGameID);
            db.Reservations.Add(reservation);
            db.SaveChanges();

            HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, reservation);
            response.Headers.Location = new Uri(Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { id = reservation.ID }));
            return response;
        }
        else
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Solution

**heymega** pointed me in the right direction by telling me to look further into the 500 error I was receiving. Using FireBug I found this in the exception message:

```
"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'."
```

I was able to remedy this by adding these lines to me WebApiConfig.cs file

```
var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
```

Comment: Put it in debug and step through the controller. At a guess, you're throwing an exception somewhere after / during saving the reservation, such that the actual save has already taken place. ApiController will send a 500 response if an exception bubbles up to it.

Comment: @SMcCrohan I added the breakpoints - and it looks like response is bein returned with a status code 201. Any other ideas?

Comment: @anwyatt You said previously the HttpStatus code was 500 and now its 201...Which is it? 0.o

If youre getting 201 then this is correct since youre returing HttpStatusCode.Created

Comment: @heymega the ajax request is receiving a 500, but when adding a breakpoint, I can see that my API controller is returning a 201.

Comment: @anwyatt Ok - have a look at the data thats in your 500 response using firebug/fiddler or any other http traffic viewer. Sounds to me like an Exception handler may have created the 500 error and your stacktrace and error message will be inside

Comment: @heymega that was the deal - I'm going to add the details of my solution to my question, but if you will modify your answer to the comment instructing me to check the exception details I will mark it as accepted. Thanks!

Comment: Never include the answer in your own question. Please, answer your own question and accept is as correct answer. That way it can become useful for other people.

Answer (score 0):

You are specifying the return data type as `JSON`

```
 dataType: "json"
```

`jQuery` is trying to parse the response to `JSON` and since it can't, it thinks the request was unsuccessful.

If you remove the dataType then jQuery will try and work it out itself and it should fix your issue.

Hope this helps

Comment: Removing `dataType: "json"` didn't seem to fix the issue - is there another datatype I should be specifying?

Comment: One other thing I have noticed - when I remove `dataType: "json"` it no longer creates a record when posting the form.

Comment: @anwyatt The datatype has no bearing on the request data being sent only on its response, so it should have still created your record.

Comment: Ah - actually you are correct. It does still create the record.